# ADB - Getting string from the device using adb shell has unexpected and weird behavior

Tags: android, string, shell, adb

I am having the weirdest problem when I try to concat 2 String in a shell script.

First, let me tell you what I want to do.
I want to create a folder in the external storage of an Android device, using `adb`. In order to do that, I first need to get the external storage folder of the device.

For that, I used this:

```
folder=$(adb shell 'echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE')
```

And it works, since if I try to run `echo $folder` the result is `/sdcard`, which is the correct external storage folder.

But I want to create a new folder inside it, called *testResults*. So, to get the full path I tried this:

```
newDir=$folder/testResults
```

The problem is that the `newDir` variable was allways having the value `/testResults`, ignoring the value of `folder`.

At first, I thought that it might be a subshell problem, i.e. the value of `folder` was not available when I tried to concat it with the new String "for some reason". But then, it got even weirder...

If I try to concat `folder` with a smaller string than `folder` ('pop', for instance), like this:

```
newDir=$folder/pop
```

This is the result when I run `echo $newDir`:

```
/popard
```

**CONCLUSION:** For some reason, the value of `folder` is being "ignored", and when it tries to concat with other string `s` it will actually replace the first `N` characters of `folder` (with `N=length(s)`).

I thought that maybe the `/s` at the beginnig of `folder` was the reason behind so much confusion, so I tried this:

```
folder=$(adb shell 'echo sdcard')
newDir=$folder/pop
echo $newDir
```

And the result is this:

```
/poprd
```

**CONSLUSION:** Something in the adb shell tool is making the strings behave anomalously.

In fact, the problem seems to be related with adb, because if I try this:

```
folder=$(echo "/sdcard")  #or even folder="/sdcard"
newDir=$folder/testResults
echo $newDir
```

The result is correct: `/sdcard/testResults`

But this gets even weirder...
I tried using files to help me, like this:

```
adb shell 'echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE' > result.txt
folder=$(cat result.txt)
newDir=$folder/pop
echo $newDir
```

The result here is `/popard` again!
If I open the file, and insert something in the line that has the string `/sdcard`, to make it (for example) `/sdcardish`, and then do this:

```
folder=$(cat result.txt)
newDir=$folder/pop
echo $newDir
```

The result is: /popardish
If I remove that line in the file and then add another one, it works fine.

I seriously don't know what is happening... 
Does anybody know what can possibly be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess there is a newline at the end of the `folder` value. Try this:

```
folder=$(adb shell 'echo -n $EXTERNAL_STORAGE')
```

Comment: Uau, thanks! :) It worked!
I was totally puzzled... And the solution was very simple. I just knew it had to be something really stupid :P